# Autoscaling cooldown maximum seconds in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

How much is the maximum cooldown seconds for autoscaling in gcp?

Haven't seen a concrete maximum limit for the cooldown parameters for autoscaling and hopefully i can get a guide since I'm new with gcp. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum cool down period can vary from application to application and Cool down period is to set the initialization period, which tells the autoscaler how long it takes for your application to initialize.  As per this [blog](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-compute-startup-script-total-execution-time/) by John Hanley , you can decide the maximum cool down period based on the  VM creation start time and end time.  This does not include the time for all the application services to get to the ready state, but does give better numbers.The Google Instance Group default value for Cool-down period default is 60 seconds. Refer to this [initialization period](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler#cool_down_period) doc for more details.